# how do I bring an uiimage out of its frame?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, frame, uipangesturerecognizer

How do I bring an image out of its frame using UIPanGestureRecognizer. Once out of the frame still receives the touches? If it not receives the touches, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another view (an invisible one) to get the gestures and then change the frame or size of the image